# How do I use javascript / jquery image resize with wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, wordpress, resize

I wan't to include this script in my wordpress theme, making it resize all of the images inside posts according to the current window height:

https://github.com/gutierrezalex/photo-resize

I've made a basic test page in my text editor and it resizes the image just fine. However, when I try to apply/include it in my wordpress theme I simply can't get it to work.

Please, any help would be much appreciated!

Here's what's between my head tags:

```
<head><!-- HEAD BEGINS -->

<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php wp_title(); ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?>">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script src="jquery-photo-resize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("img").photoResize({
        bottomSpacing: 15
        });
    });
</script>

<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/favicon.ico" />

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:700,400,500,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<?php wp_head(); ?>

</head><!-- HEAD ENDS -->
```

And here's the script, that's located in the same folder (file name: jquery-photo-resize.js):

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.5.1.min.js" />

/*
* Adjust photo on browser window resize
* 
* @example: $('selector').photoResize();
* 
* @example:
$('selector').photoResize({
    bottomSpacing:"Bottom Spacing adjustment"
});
*/

(function ($) {

$.fn.photoResize = function (options) {

    var element = $(this), 
        defaults = {
            bottomSpacing: 10
        };

    $(element).load(function () {
        updatePhotoHeight();

        $(window).bind('resize', function () {
            updatePhotoHeight();
        });
    });

    options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    function updatePhotoHeight() {
        var o = options, 
            photoHeight = $(window).height();

        $(element).attr('height', photoHeight - o.bottomSpacing);
    }
};

}(jQuery));
```

My current functions.php:

```
<?php
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'my_post_image_html', 10, 3 );

function my_post_image_html( $html, $post_id, $post_image_id ) {

$html = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post_id ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( get_the_title( $post_id ) ) . '">' . $html . '</a>';
return $html;
}

function register_my_menu() {
register_nav_menu('top-menu',__( 'Top Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );

function righter_filter_ptags($content) {
$content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
$content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<iframe .*>*.<\/iframe>)\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1', $content);
$content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<samp .*>*.<\/samp>)\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1', $content);
return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'righter_filter_ptags');
```

Comment: It is incredibly important that you post what you have tried so far so we can figure out what you may have done wrong or missed. Without that it's just heresay. Would you be able to post the code?

Comment: how are you including the js files ?? some code plzz

Comment: @zillaofthegods
Sorry about that, I just edited the post and added the code!

Comment: @Vaibs_Cool Sorry, just updated the post with the code!

Comment: Thanks for posting it, that should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay first and foremost. For all wordpress scripts. enquing is incredibly important. So take your links and do this:

The best way to avoid asset conflicts is by properly enquing the files. To do this you must use [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

a good way to do this is to put it as part of a function in your functions.php file like so

1. create a function
2. insert `wp_register_script` into the function
3. then insert `wp_enqeue_script` into the function
4. use add_action(), to initlize the enqueue-ing process

---

so -

```
function load_scripts() {
  wp_register_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array( 'scriptyouwillwaittobeloaded' ) );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name' );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');
```

---

In this example the function load_scripts() would then be called in the header.php file. Take a look at wp_register_script as well to get a better understanding of the arguments for that as well, but in summary -

first argument: is the name you want to use as reference to this script

second argument: is the actual link to the script

third argument: is the script that you want to load before this script (the script you want to wait for before this script loads)

---

and for wp_enqueue_script, the argument is merely a reference to the name (the first argument of wp_register_script)

---

**the add_action function arguments:**

first argument: the function you are "hooking" into

second argument: the function you created that will be "hooked"

---

Secondly - is `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>` actually the name of jquery's remote file? Try loading your own localized version. Also, make sure nothing else is loading jquery (like a boilerplate, what have you).

---

In summary - Your code isn't loading as a result of how wordpress works. Your resize script is acutally being looked for in the root folder, not the wordpress themese folder, as a result it is unable to be found. A quick fix would be to do this `<script src=<?php echo "'" . get_template_directory_uri() . "/jquery-photo-resize.js'" ?>></script>` However you should seriously consider enqueuing.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! But I'm kinda lost...
The script code and header code comes from the author. However, the script name is jquery-photo-resize.js, which is stored locally in the theme folder. I assume that http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js is the JS framework which has to be loaded in advanced in order for the script to work. But I'm pretty new at anything/everything that has to do with javascript(s), so what do I know. I just updated the post with my current functions file. I can't figure out what I need to do in order for it to work. Thanks a lot for helping out!!!

Comment: Take a look at what I added at the bottom, it should help.

Comment: Thanks!!! The quick-fix will have to do until I figure out how to do it the correct way... There's one issue however, which was not present when I made the basic test page/image in my text editor. The resizing is not proportional when used in wordpress – any idéa what's causing that?

http://niklaslundberg.com/turkisk-peber/

Comment: Hey, no problem. Don't forget to upvote and check as rite answer if it worked (i love my sweet sweet rep). Hrmm, well depending on how you're outputting your image, it could be affected by some core css files and wordpress styling (if you are dynamically outputting an image). It's hard to say without having used the plugin or access to code as well. Would be suggested to open another topic for this alone.